# Google API supports .NET but not Unity?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, google-api-dotnet-client

I was working on [Google API](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client) and in that link, it says that it supports .NET Framework 4.0 but not Unity.

To my knowledge, Unity runs on .NET 4.x equivalent.

How can the API support .NET Framework 4.0 but not support Unity?

Is this related to Android support in Unity, which is used when apps are built for Android?

It's very confusing for me.

Comment: "Unsupported" could mean "we haven't tested it".

Comment: It is unsupported and there is no plans on supporting as the library is currently maintenance mode.   Its been tested by a number of people like you it does not work. [#531](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/531)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From these FAQ:

### Why aren't Unity, Xamarin or UWP supported?

> At a team discussion in October 2018 we made the decision to not
>   proceed with support for these platforms. We don't see evidence that
>   there would be enough usage to justify the technical work and
>   infrastructure required for us to **fully support** these extra platforms.
>
> We will revisit this decision on a regular basis, in case the
>   situation changes.

In a nutshell this means they won't be testing or improving support.

But despite the above, I have successfully managed to integrate YouTube API from that repository.